# Circle tangent to $x$-axis and $y$-axis

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I show that a circle that is tangent to $x$-axis and $y$-axis has radius $R$ and center $(R,R)$ using algebra?

So I have this concept about it.
Since the point on $y$ tangent to the circle (I'll call it $Y$) is $(0,Y)$ and on $x$ (I'll call it $X$) is $(X,0)$. Let's call the center $E$.
From $X$ to $E$ and $Y$ to $E$ are the radii.
So $XE=YE$.  Then I'll use the distance formula (which I don't know how to render here) but I can't continue from it.

So, how can I continue?

Comment: Please add what you have tried.

Comment: You have already solved the problem. Rename $XE=YE=r$ and the co-ordinates of the center becomes $(r,r)$.

Comment: How does it become $(r,r)$?

Comment: It seems to me that you are assuming that the center of the circle is in the first quadrant.  Otherwise, the center could also be $(-r, r)$ or $(-r, -r)$ or $(r, -r)$.   Also, to type the distance formula $d(P_1, P_2) = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}$ for points $P(x_1, y_1)$ and $P_2(x_2, y_2)$, type d(P_1, P_2) = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2} when you are in math mode.

Answer (score 2):

The equation to a circle is $$(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$$We know the circle is tangent to $x,y$ axi.

We also know the derivative of the circle equation (with respect to $x$): $$2x+2(y-y_c)y'=0$$$$y'=\frac x{y-y_c}$$$$y=\sqrt{r^2-(x-x_c)^2}+y_c$$$$y'=\frac x{\sqrt{r^2-(x-x_c)^2}}$$

Setting the denominator equal to $0$, we get $$0=\sqrt{r^2-(x-x_c)^2}$$$$x=\pm r+x_c$$For this to be our $y-intercept$, we have $x=0$.$$x_c=\pm r$$This puts our $x-coordinate$ for the center to actually be $\pm r$.

We can repeat the process by differentiating with respect to $y$ and setting the denominator equal to $0$ to get $y_c=\pm r$.

Comment: What if i was given point A(1,2) which is pass through by the circle? Like an addition to the question. I can still use your way and how?

Comment: @User2524 Then substitute that point into the original circle equation to find $r$.

Comment: @User2524 You can still use my way because my method doesn't use any points, it takes all $x,y$ values to solve.

Comment: @User2524 When given a point, proceed with my method as if you didn't know the point.  Substitute the point to find $r$ at the very end, after doing everything.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the diagram below of a circle with its center in the first quadrant that is tangent to both coordinate axes:

[image: circle_with_center_in_first_quadrant_that_is_tangent_to_both_coordinate_axes]

Let $(x, y)$ be the center of a circle with radius $r$ (we do not assume the center of the circle is in the first quadrant).  If the circle is tangent to the $y$-axis, then the point of tangency must be $(0, y)$ since the perpendicular to the $y$-axis must be horizontal.  Since the distance from the center to the point of tangency is $r$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
|x - 0| & = r\\
|x| & = r\\
x & = \pm r
\end{align*}
Since the circle is tangent to the $y$-axis, the point of tangency must be $(x, 0)$ since the perpendicular to the $x$-axis must be vertical.  Since the distance from the center to the point of tangency is $r$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
|y - 0| & = r\\
|y| & = r\\
y & = \pm r
\end{align*}
These equations lead to the four possible solutions $(\pm r, \pm r)$ for the center of the circle, as shown in the diagram below.

[image: four_circles_tangent_to_the_coordinate_axes]

Comment: I like pretty pictures.  :)